# I have the problem reading spaces in a txt file i copied from an xlsx file

Tags: c++

I copied some numbers from a xlsx file and pasted them in a txt file. I want to use the getline() function to read the numbers individually by stopping at a whitespace. My problem is that the white space allthough it appears on the txt file is not recognized by the program. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include  <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int i;
char ch;
void readtxtfiles();
string line, first_n, second_n, third_n, fourth_n, fifth_n, joker_n;

int main()

{
    system("chcp 1253");
    readtxtfiles();
}

void readtxtfiles()
{
    ifstream jokerfiles("Joker_2015.txt");
    string line;
    //jokerfiles >> noskipws >> first_n>>second_n>>third_n>>fourth_n>>fifth_n;
    for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        getline(jokerfiles, line);
        stringstream ss(line);
        getline(ss, first_n, ' ');
        getline(ss, second_n, ' ');
        cout << first_n << endl;
        cout << second_n << endl;
    }
} // added by user4581301
```

Here is a link to the input file https://filebin.net/e3404yceh41audys

Comment: Can you post the input file?

Comment: Here is a picture of the list and the space https://ibb.co/MSfCRqV

Comment: Add that picture to your question.

Comment: Please add the input file (or a reduction of it that exhibits the same misbehaviour) to the question. Normally I'd migrate the file myself, but I'm not downloading some anonymous file onto to my computer from some anonymous site. The Internet is littered with broken computers because their user made that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really tell from the screenshot, but are you sure those are spaces and not tabs?
You can try replacing `' '` in your getline with `'\t'`

```
getline(ss, first_n,'\t');
```

Comment: Well just like that problem solved. Thanks a lot man. I spend so much time wondering why spaces are not recognized that I didn't stop to thing if there is a much simpler explanation. Literally drowning a spoon of water. Thanks again!

Comment: Note: `getline`'s not needed inside the loop. `>>` will automatically eat all whiespace for you, be it space or tab. That bit of code reduces to `ss >> first_n >> second_n;`